# Add two anonymous type list

Tags: c#

I have two anonymous list, I want to combine them

```
var med= data1.Select(i => new { DisplayText=i.PROPRIETARYNAME, Value = i.PRODUCTID, Type="med" }).ToList();

var cmed = data2.Select(i => new { DisplayText = i.MedicationName, Value = i.MedicationId, Type = "cmed" }).ToList();
```

Now i want to add both of them into another variable.

Comment: have you tried join ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the anonymous type has the same properties (in the same order) you can use [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var med = data1
  .Select(i => new { DisplayText=i.PROPRIETARYNAME, Value = i.PRODUCTID, Type="med" });   
var cmed = data2
  .Select(i => new { DisplayText = i.MedicationName, Value = i.MedicationId, Type = "cmed" });
var both = med.Concat(cmed).ToList();
```

or [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if you want to remove duplicates);

```
var both = med.Union(cmed).ToList();
```

Comment: The question may have been edited or I may be blind, but what is the difference in this version?

Comment: @Jon: OP doesn't use a method to combine/merge both, he just shows two lists.

Comment: The first sentence threw me off... too emphasized perhaps?

Comment: @Jon: I have edited my answer now. So all conditions are already met to use `Concat`/`Union`. I've also removed the two redundant `ToList`s.